# QGIS- QgsProject.instance()- Possible to load only into memory/object (not into the UI?)

Tags: pyqgis

I've come from ArcGIS/ArcPy where the behaviour for projects was either: `doc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")` to open the current project as an object name doc
doc = `arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C\pathToSomeProjectFile\Project.mxd")` to open that document as an object name doc. Neither method would actually load the layers etc within that map document into the interface.

In QGIS, there seem to be similar options `project = QgsProject.instance()` uses the currently open project (which may just be a blank canvas or a complex set of layers, layouts etc) then `project.read(r'C\pathToSomeProjectFile\Project.qgz")` to load an existing project

This, however, loads all those layers into the interface rather than just into an object. I don't want that....I want to use the template project with all the layers symbolised and a layout created as an object, run the code against it to select, zoom to a feature, export a map, then close out- I don't want this process to change anything in the current project.
Currently my code only works by first opening the template project, running the code (without the project.read() line, then closing it....but the project is large and contains lots of weblayers so is very slow to open and the code also seems to 'break' the project)

Is it possible to simply reference an external project file/assign it to an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible using the `QgsProject` class with the `.read()` method

from https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsProject.html:

> QgsProject is available both as a singleton (QgsProject.instance()) and for use as standalone objects. The QGIS project singleton always gives access to the canonical project reference open within the main QGIS application.

[image]

As you can see, the two `QgsProject` instances contain different layers. with this done you can interact with the layers of the two projects

```python
project1 = QgsProject.instance()

project2 = QgsProject()
project2.read("path/to/other/project.qgz")

project1.mapLayers()  # Gives you access to the first/main project' layers
project2.mapLayers()  # Gives you access to the second project's layers
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know/think that. Could you add the script/outputs as text?

Comment: If my answer answered your question, accept it please